# While loop and how to stop it in a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am having trouble with this data validation program I have for an assignment. I have trouble with this while loop here for some reason it continues to run indefinitely. Other while loops run in my code alright but this function here doesn't...

```
def menu():                                                                                             
    pick = None
    while pick != "q" or pick != "Q":
        print """
    \n

    Welcome to my password validation program.

    1 - New Account
    2 - Login
    q - Quit

    """
    pick = raw_input("What do you want to do?:  ")
    # Quit
    if pick == "q":
        print "\t   Thanks for coming Good-bye."
        raw_input("\nPress any key to exit")
    # New Account
    elif pick == "1":
        main()                                                                                      
    # Login
    elif pick == "2":
        if ps == 100:
            login()                                                                                 
        else:
            print "Sorry no password has been set. please create a new account."
    else:
        print "Sorry, but", pick, "isn't a valid choice."

menu()
```

---

Had the code around the wrong way, both your answers were correct. @jonrsharpe @tdelaney

```
   def menu():
        print \
        """
        \n

        Welcome to my password validation program.

        1 - New Account
        2 - Login
        q - Quit

        """

        pick = None
        pick = raw_input("What do you want to do?:  ")
        # Quit
        if pick == "q":
            print "\t   Thanks for coming Good-bye."
            raw_input("\nPress any key to exit")
        # New Account
        elif pick == "1":
            main()                                                                                      
        # Login
        elif pick == "2":
            if ps == 100:
                login()                                                                                 
            else:
                print "Sorry no password has been set. please create a new account."
        else:
            print "Sorry, but", pick,"isn't a valid choice."

    menu()
```

Comment: You realise that only the `print` line is inside the `while` loop?

Comment: So how does this stop the infinite loop. I understand the print line prints out the following text but what does it have to do with the infinite loop

Comment: ***Only* the `print` line.** In which you **do not change the value of `pick`**. The whole rest of your function only runs *after* the loop terminates, which *it cannot*.

Comment: `pick = raw_input("What do you want to do?:  ")` is not part of the `while` loop... you would need to indent it and the following lines to be in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your indentation, 

Do this:

```
def menu():                                                                                             
    pick = None
    while pick != "q" or pick != "Q":
        print """
        \n

        Welcome to my password validation program.

        1 - New Account
        2 - Login
        q - Quit

        """
        pick = raw_input("What do you want to do?:  ")
        # Quit
        if pick == "q":
            print "\t   Thanks for coming Good-bye."
            raw_input("\nPress any key to exit")
        # New Account
        elif pick == "1":
            main()
        # Login
        elif pick == "2":
            if ps == 100:
                login()
            else:
                print "Sorry no password has been set. please create a new account."
        else:
            print "Sorry, but", pick, "isn't a valid choice."

menu()
```

the value assignment of `pick` parameter must be in while loop scope.
Another thing is here is that `main` and `login` functions are not defined so make sure it is in your local scope or imported to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have had some copy/paste errors while posting your code here...if not your `print """` line is going to keep printing as long as pick is not equal to q or Q.